# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') + TypeORM Repository

Tags: postgresql, repository, nestjs, typeorm, repository-pattern

I'm working with **typeORM** and Postgres in Nest.js and I'm separating my Repository from Service.

The problem is the **entityRepository()** decorator is not registering one of my repositories and everything points to it being fine as the same code is creating another entity's repository fine.

I've really searched and deleted the module twice thinking I might have missed something along the way, but nothing is working. When I do **`console.log(this)`** in the repository I get an empty object **`{}`**...

Below is the **(module, repository, and entity)** for the stock-analysis module

**stock-analysis.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { StockAnalysisController } from './stock-analysis.controller';
import { StockAnalysisRepository } from './stock-analysis.repository';
import { StockAnalysisService } from './stock-analysis.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([StockAnalysisRepository])],
  controllers: [StockAnalysisController],
  providers: [StockAnalysisService, StockAnalysisRepository],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
})
export class AnalysisModule {}
```

**stock-analysis.repository.ts**

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { StockAnalysisDto } from '../dtos/analysis/stock-analysis-dto';
import { StockAnalysis } from './stock-analysis.entity';
import { User } from '../user/user.entity';

@EntityRepository(StockAnalysis)
export class StockAnalysisRepository extends Repository<StockAnalysis> {

  async analyseStock(user: User, stockAnalysisDto: StockAnalysisDto) {
    const { stock } = stockAnalysisDto;
    console.log({ this: this });
    // console.log({ stock });
    // console.log(user);

    const stocksToAnalyse = this.create();
  }
}
```

**stock-analysis.entity.ts**

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class StockAnalysis {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  Id: string;

  @Column('text', { array: true })
  stocks: string[];

  @Column()
  userId: string;
}
```

I'm really stuck, ran out of ideas. Any form of help will be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are missing the `@Injectable()` decoratator for your custom repository. Remember you need this when using dependency injection.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { StockAnalysisDto } from '../dtos/analysis/stock-analysis-dto';
import { StockAnalysis } from './stock-analysis.entity';
import { User } from '../user/user.entity';

@Injectable()
@EntityRepository(StockAnalysis)
export class StockAnalysisRepository extends Repository<StockAnalysis> {
   constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
    super(StockAnalysis, dataSource.createEntityManager());
  }
}
```